# Set DataSource size in PageKeyedDataSource to get placeholder effect

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack, android-paging

I am using the **Paging Library** from *Android Architecture Component*. I am trying to load data through server, without any local database.

My `DataSource` class extends `PageKeyedDataSource`.

Below is my `Paging.Config` customisation,

```
PagedList.Config pageConfig = (new PagedList.Config.Builder())
            .setPageSize(20)
            .setInitialLoadSizeHint(30)
            .setPrefetchDistance(5)
            .setEnablePlaceholders(true)
            .build();
```

I have enabled placeholders & that lands me to managing `null` in 
`PagedListAdapter` class. I have done that something like below,

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyEventViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Article mArticle = getItem(position);

    if (mArticle != null) {
        holder.txtTitle.setText(mArticle.getTitle());
        holder.txtAuthor.setText(mArticle.getAuthor());
        holder.txtDesc.setText(mArticle.getDescription());
    } else {
        holder.txtTitle.setText("...");
        holder.txtAuthor.setText("......");
        holder.txtDesc.setText(".........");
    }
}
```

I am unable to see placeholders at the end of a list before next API call.

My question is, Is there a way that I can **specify the size of list** *after first API call*? As my API is returning total number of items to be expected from the query. If not possible that what else I can do to see placeholders for my list.

**Note** : I cannot switch to `ItemKeyedDataSource` or `PositionalDataSource` because my API is set to respond on page basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this I think you need to do loadInitial inside

```
callback.onResult(mArticles, 0, SIZE_OF_TOTAL_ITEMS, null, 2L);
```

loadBefore

```
callback.onResult(mArticles, params.key - 1);
```

loadAfter

```
callback.onResult(mArticles, params.key + 1);
```

And there is SIZE_OF_TOTAL_ITEMS must be known at initial load time.